# Can anyone get this addon to work? Resolve Camera Tracks.py

Tags: add-on

https://github.com/Uberi/MotionTracking.

I've trying versions 2.83, 2.92,2.93,3.00 and i can't get it to work.
I managed to install it by copying the code into a new file, but It doesn't give me the command that it describes in step 14:
"Select all the generated empties, and invoke View3D > Object > Resolve Camera Tracks."

I f3 searched for it and looked on the ui for View3d. If anyone can Get this to work would you show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like it's just a Version Number problem. I tried to run it as a script and it worked, while installing it as an add-on gives a prompt to upgrade to 2.80 in the Add-on interface. There were a high number of API breaking changes jumping from V2.79 to V2.80 so add-on developers were required to manually change the version number in their add-on, otherwise it wouldn't even register.

On line 12, replace

```
"blender": (2, 75, 0),
```

with

```
"blender": (2, 80, 0),
```

And you should be good to go. It didn't throw any error so I assume it's working and I can find the operator you're looking for. Unfortunately I don't have the data to actually test it so I can't say for sure it works. At least the add-on registers now.

Comment: Thank you. that solved that problem.   now i'm getting this error. I'll have to try a better track maybe. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Office\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\Resolve Camera Tracks.py", line 45, in execute
    resolved_empties.append(self.add_resolved_empty(point_targets))
  File "C:\Users\Office\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\Resolve Camera Tracks.py", line 182, in add_resolved_empty
    resolved.empty_draw_type = "SPHERE"
AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'empty_draw_type'

Comment: replace all instances of `empty_draw_type` by `empty_display_type`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Office\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\Resolve Camera Tracks.py", line 45, in execute
    resolved_empties.append(self.add_resolved_empty(point_targets))
  File "C:\Users\Office\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\Resolve Camera Tracks.py", line 183, in add_resolved_empty
    resolved.empty_draw_size = 0.1
AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'empty_draw_size'

Thank you! The error changed a bit. Oh, it's creating a empty but it's at the origin.

Comment: @jitone1 Same deal, replace `empty_draw_size` with `empty_display_size`

Comment: wow. so is this what programing is like? one error after another? I seriously have a lot of respect for what you do. Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Office\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\Resolve Camera Tracks.py", line 53, in execute
    for empty in resolved_empties: empty.select = True
AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'select'

location: <unknown location>:-1

Comment: @jitone1 yeah that's pretty much it ^^ Let's continue this discussion in chat : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126293/updating-resolve-camera-tracks-py